# Any way to get the first few characters of filename in DOS batch file Programming

Tags: batch-file

I am using this in my program

```
for %%I in (*.txt) do (
```

The filename is in `%%I`.

Now i want to separate the first 2 chracters, next 3 characters, separately.

Is this possible in DOS or Cmd.exe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

```
set first2=%%I:~0,2% && set next3=%%I:~3,3%
```

I think.. geez, its been a while!

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.mp3) do ( 
  set oldName=%%a 
  Set newName=!oldName:~3! 
  Ren "!oldName!" "!newName!" ) 
exit
```

_Strip 3.cmd   is a good name to save this to. Works for me.
I have it (*.mp3) to only work with mp3 files ... you can change it to (*.*)

Change the ~3! to another number if you want to...... ~4! will truncate the first 4 characters of the file name.

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell:

```
$first2=$string.substring(0,2)
$next3=$string.substring(2,3)
```